# Azure ML - Can not list/load registered Datasets via Python SDK

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

I'm quite new to Azure ML and Python. I created some datasets using both the Azure ML GUI and the Python SDK:

[image]

Now I want to load these datasets in a Pandas Dataframe. But when I run

```
Dataset.get_all(workspace=workspace)
```

I got an empty list.

[image]

Do I miss something? I'm using the version 0.2.7. of azureml and Version 1.46.0. of azureml-core.

I also tried

```
workspace.datasets
```

But also got an empty result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the dataset in AzureML Data already saved, here is python code you can run from anywhere to access the dataset, authenticating as a ServicePrincipal:

```
from azureml.core.authentication import ServicePrincipalAuthentication
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core import Dataset

svc_pr = ServicePrincipalAuthentication(
    tenant_id="your-tenant-id-here",
    service_principal_id="your-service-principal-id",
    service_principal_password='your-service-principal-password')

ws = Workspace.from_config(path='config/file/path/config.json', auth=svc_pr)


# Get one dataset
ds = Dataset.get_by_name(ws, 'Your dataset name from AzureML Data')
df = ds.to_pandas_dataframe()

#Get all datasets
ds_all = Dataset.get_all(ws)
for registration_name, dataset in ds_all.items():
    df_instance = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
    # .... do something with the data
```

The config.json file could look like this:

```
{
    "subscription_id": "your-subscription-id",
    "resource_group": "your-resource-group",
    "workspace_name": "your-workspace-name"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to have the datasets in the workspace in the form of tabular. If the dataset is in another format, we can’t retrieve the datasets in the workspace.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am choosing Local files

[image]

[image]

**Code:**

```
ws = Workspace.get(name="your ws name",
               subscription_id='your subscription ID',
               resource_group='your resource group')
```

Then using the workspace details, we can connect and get dataset details.

```
Dataset.get_all(ws)
```

**Output:**

```
{'churn3': DatasetRegistration(id='b9fb5e3d-4893-4847-9f2e-497d85edd3b3', name='churn3', version=1, description='', tags={}), 'churn2': DatasetRegistration(id='007a6e1a-268c-409e-adbb-d5437946c4ef', name='churn2', version=1, description='', tags={})}
```

Achieved the result.

Comment: Thank's for clarification. I did not found this strange restriction in the docu. Did you know, if this is going to change, i.e. will it be possible to load other dataset formats into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: loading other formats of dataset is not an issue. but retrieving them with the registered workspace details is only available for tabular datasets as mentioned in the answer. In future it may be extended to other formats too. But for now, as mentioned in the question, the requirement is satisfied the procedure mentioned in solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to do it.

You have to upload the files manually.

In the azure ML studio:

- Data/Data Assets -> Create
- Type -> File (Dataset types from Azure ML v1 APIs)

Then you call:

```
Dataset.get_all(ws)
```

It returns all datasets, both File and Tabular.